# Why are filename ordering rules different on graphical/non-graphical linux programs?

Tags: linux, filenames, ls

Here is the output of an `ls`:

```
x-15.txt
x-1617.txt
x-2411.txt
x-24.txt
x-ae.txt
x-afag.txt
x-bdaa.txt
x-bd.txt
```

Note that `x-1617` comes before `x-24` and the same ordering rule seems to apply to the corresponding alphabetic filenames.

This is fine. This is what I have come to expect.

In various graphical programs (e.g. Dolphin, Gwenview), the numeric filenames are ordered differently -- `x-24` would come before `x-1617``-- presumably because someone decided that the interpreted numeric value of the digit sequence was more useful.

This is causing problems where the order of presentation is important. I don't think things were always this way.

Is there a system-wide policy option that will change this for all programs on Ubuntu/KDE? I want all programs to use `ls`-style ASCII ordering.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` by default uses 'alphabetical sort', meaning 15 < 2. It seems like the other applications you are using uses 'version sort', meaning 2 < 15. You can choose version order for ls through `ls -v`.

I don't know of a system-wide policy that organizes the file sorting criteria, however I thought providing you with the proper terms of alphabetic vs version sort may help you find what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

check the value of the LC_COLLATE environment variable. If set to "POSIX", it should do the 'alphabetical sort' in all cases.